# Using an Index with foreach-object in powershell

Tags: powershell, indexing, get-childitem, foreach-object

I have this code:

`Get-ChildItem FOLDERNAMEHERE *.png| ForEach-Object { $_.Name } > fileNames.txt`

It prints off a list of file Names, and I want to change it to out just print out an index of numbers instead of Names.

Comment: Please upvote this [PowerShell GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13772) which proposes to add an automatic `$PSIndex` variable. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To output sequence numbers starting with `1` (replace `$i = 0` with `$i = -1` to start with `0`):

```
Get-ChildItem FOLDERNAMEHERE *.png |
  ForEach-Object -Begin { $i = 0 } -Process { (++$i) }
```

Note that the variable `$i` lives on after this command, and, if it preexisted before running the command, effectively changes it, because the script blocks passed to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) run directly in the caller's scope.

The increment assignment operation ([`++`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators#the-increment-and-decrement-operators)) is wrapped in [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) so as to also *output* the incremented value (assignment statements produce no output by default).

As an aside:

- [GitHub issue #13772](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13772) proposes introducing an [*automatic*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) index variable for use in pipelines, such as `$PSIndex`, which would simplify the solution to:

  ```
  Get-ChildItem FOLDERNAMEHERE *.png | ForEach-Object { $PSIndex + 1 }
  ```

---

Non-streaming alternative, using `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-):

```
if ($count = (Get-ChildItem FOLDERNAMEHERE *.png).Count) {
  1..$count
}
```

Note: Non-streaming means that the results of the `Get-ChildItem` call are collected in full, up front in order to determine the upper limit for the sequence numbers.

Similarly, the `1..$count` range operation collects the elements between the range endpoints in an array up front before beginning to produce visible output. See the comments for a discussion.

In other words: Go with the streaming, `ForEach-Object`-based solution if the `Get-ChildItem` command produces a lot of output objects and you want to start emitting sequence numbers as quickly as possible.

Comment: What surprised me about the range operator, is the fact that it actually creates an array which is then enumerated. I would have thought that it creates a lazy-evaluated sequence instead. But you get a noticable delay when doing `1..100MB` for instance. Compare with `[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Range(0, 100MB)` which starts to enumerate immediately. I wonder why PowerShell choose that design.

Comment: Interestingly, `foreach( $i in 0..100MB ) { $i }` also enumerates immediately, so it might be preferred over the more "elegant" `1..n`, at least if we expect `n` to be a large number.

Comment: `0..100MB |% { $_ }` also enumerates without delay. So the question stays, why `0..100MB` does not?

Comment: @zett42, I haven't looked at the source code, so this is in part speculative: `..` appears to be special among operators in that it _is_ capable of streaming the elements between 
the range endpoints to the pipeline. In other words: I suspect it doesn't actually create an array;
instead, in the context of an _expression_ - which `0..100mb` _in isolation_ is - it is PowerShell
that collects the streamed elements in an `[object[]]` array, as it would in an expression such
as `(Get-ChildItem).Count`.

Comment: Only if you connect a streaming consumer to a `..` expression does
the streaming behavior surface. If you make the `..` operation participate in a larger expression,
the collect-up-front behavior kicks in again; e.g. `, 0 + 1..100mb  | % { $_; pause }`

Comment: @zett42, that `foreach( $i in 0..100MB ) { $i }` effectively streams is surprising, given that
streaming _command_ output is _collected in full, up front_ in `foreach` statements; e.g.:
`foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem $HOME -File -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore) { $f; pause }`
Therefore, in the case at hand, if a `Get-ChildItem` call determines the number of sequence numbers to produce,
using the pipeline with `ForEach-Object` is your only option if you want to avoid a delay stemming from up-front collection.

Comment: @zett42 that's an interesting question, I was unaware using a loop would start enumerating immediately, `0..[int]::MaxValue` will instantly throw but `foreach($i in 0..[int]::MaxValue) { $i }` enumerates

Comment: Nice find, @Santiago. There must be code that tries to allocate an array up front in _non-streaming_ contexts, which, due to `[int]` arithmetic, causes the overflow error with `0..[int]::MaxValue`, and with lower values can still cause an "Array dimensions exceeded supported range" error (try `0..([int]::MaxValue-1)`). In _streaming_ contexts, the only thing that matters is whether the endpoints are `[int]` values, thereby effectively permitting a maximum of `[int]::MaxValue+1` values.

Comment: Correction, @Santiago; Streaming use effectively permits _[uint]_::MaxValue + 1 elements, namely: `([int]::MinValue)..([int]::MaxValue) | % { $_; pause }`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Another proof that `foreach` enumerates ranges: `foreach($i in 0..0) { $foreach.GetType().Name }` prints `RangeEnumerator`. Compare with `foreach($i in (0..0)) { $foreach.GetType().Name }` which prints `ArrayEnumerator`.